# How to extract the difference given by the Levensthein distance?

Tags: python, string, levenshtein-distance

The Levensthein distance provides a number which is the total number of differences between two strings. My question is: is it possible to retrieve, instead of the number, what are these differences? For example

```
a = "MyTest"
b = "MynewTest"
```

The Levensthein will be 3, but how do I retrieve and store the string `"new"`?
I might combine the `ndiff` library but is there an already available function?

Comment: I think this can be achieved without Levensthein distance. But if you want to use the distance, then I think this post can be informative and you only need to index where the minimum of the diagonal value, first corresponding element +1, second corresponding element + 1 is:  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/02/a-simple-guide-to-metrics-for-calculating-string-similarity/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import difflib
print(''.join([i[-1] for i in difflib.ndiff("MyTest", "MynewTest") if i[0] == '+']))
```

Output:

```
new
```